# Upload,retrieve and delete images in amazon S3

Tags: angular, file-upload, amazon-s3

Hello i want to upload images in s3 from my angular2 application without using `aws-sdk`.I found this link which explained about file upload without any library https://github.com/ntheg0d/angular2_aws_s3/blob/master/app/upload/upload.component.ts .I followed the following steps to upload image

```
<form (ngSubmit)="upload()">
    <input name="file" type="file" size="60" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

And this is my upload logic

```
    onChange(event: any) {
      var file = event.target.files[0];
       var queryString = 'filename=' + filename +
        '&content_type=' + event.target.files[0].type; 
       this.uploadSrvc.GetS3Credentials(queryString).subscribe((response: 
        any) => {
           this.upload(file, response);
       });
   }
```

Here the GetS3Credentials gets the bucket name and other credentails and calls the actual event to upload

```
    upload(file: any, response: any) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Build AWS S3 Request
    formData.append('key', response.params.key);
    formData.append('acl', response.params.acl);
    formData.append('content-Type', response.params['content-type']);
    //Put in your access key here
    formData.append('x-amz-algorithm', response.params['x-amz-algorithm']);

    formData.append('x-amz-credential', response.params['x-amz-credential']);
    formData.append('x-amz-date', response.params['x-amz-date']);
    formData.append('policy', response.params['policy']);
    formData.append('x-amz-signature', response.params['x-amz-signature']);
    formData.append('success_action_status', response.params['success_action_status']);
    formData.append('file', file);

    xhr.open('POST', response.endpoint_url, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

The Upload event works perfectly and i am able to upload the image.Now i want to retrieve the image from server without any library.can somebody please tell me how can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried? What does the API look like? What does it return etc. etc. etc.

Comment: I don't know what i have done is correct. I have modified the line in above code to `xhr.open('GET', response.endpoint_url, true);` .If i am wrong please correct me @Carsten